# Calculation of Legendre Polynominals via Rodrigues Formula

Tags: special-functions, polynomials

I want to calculate Legendre Polynomials via Rodrigues formula for n=0,...,10

I wrote this down but how can I calculate n = 0,...,10 ?

$$P_n(x)=\frac1{2^n n!}\frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n}(x^2-1)^n$$

```
p[n_, x_] := 1/(2^n n!) D[(q^2 - 1)^n, {q, n}] /. q -> x ;
```

should be simple but I don't get it..

thank you for help!

Comment: Try p[n_, x_] := Expand[1/(2^n n!) D[(q^2 - 1)^n, {q, n}] /. q -> x] .

Comment: ok thanks so far. And how to define n = 0,...,10 so it will be calculated?

Comment: The command Table[p[n, x], {n, 0, 10}] does the job.

Comment: be blessed! table command, thak you so much! :)

Answer (score 3):

There are some tweaks you can use to improve results. Try this code:

```
p[n_, x_: x] := D[(#^2 - 1)^n, {#, n}]/(2 n)!! &@x // Expand;
Table[{n, LegendreP[n, x], p[n]}, {n, 0, 10}] // Column
```

where the value of `LegendreP[n, x] // Expand` is the same as `p[n]`.

Comment: Just for completeness, here I give a version which also evaluates the Legendrepolynom for numerical x-value: `p[n_, x_: x] = Derivative[n][(#^2 - 1)^n /(2 n)!! &][x]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks for that comment!